# getJSON PHP não mostra resultado

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, getjson

Estou fazendo uma consulta simples via getJSON, mas não esta retornando os valores para ser mostrado.

Arquivo **testeJson.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    //$("#email").click(function() {

        nome = "listar";
        $.getJSON("testeConexaoMobileJson.php", {acao:nome}, function(json){
            $("#nome").val(json[0].nome);
            $("#email").val(json[0].email);
        });
    //});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Cardápio de Pizzas</h1>
    <div id="email"></div>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo **testeConexaoMobileJson.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','','',''); if($mysqli->connect_error){echo "Erro";exit();}

if($_GET['acao'] == 'listar'){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
    $rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cadastro");
    $row_rs = $rs->fetch_assoc();
    $row = $rs->fetch_array();  
    $registros = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

    while($campos=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { 
        extract($campos); 
        $Array = Array(); 

        $Array[] = Array(
                            "nome"  => "$nome",
                            "email" => "$email",
                        ); 

        $json_encode = json_encode($Array); 
        echo $json_encode; 
    } 


}
?>
```

Resultado do arquivo testeConexaoMobileJson.php

**Inspetor**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado**:

> [{"nome":"Tiago","email":"email1@hotmail.com"}][{"nome":"Tiago","email":"email2@hotmail.com"}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu códigos está muito redundante, basicamente o que você precisa é isso:

```
$rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cadastro");

$registros = $rs->num_rows;

$arr = array();
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $arr[] = $row;
} 

$json_encode = json_encode($arr); 
echo $json_encode;
```

**Problemas:**

`$row_rs` recebe o primeiro registro da consulta em um array associativo, `$row` faz a mesma coisa exceto que recebe um array indexado por números e um associativo. Dica elimine a linha da atribuição do `$row`.

```
$rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cadastro");
$row_rs = $rs->fetch_assoc();
$row = $rs->fetch_array();  


 while($campos=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { 
    extract($campos); 
    $Array = Array(); 
    $Array[] = Array("nome"  => "$nome", "email" => "$email",); 
    $json_encode = json_encode($Array); 
    echo $json_encode; 
}
```

Não faz muito sentido usar `extract()` elemine ele. A cada volta do while `$array` é resetado com um array vazio, a linha seguinte já tem um erro de sintaxe, yep um vírgula sobrando lá no final.

A conversão do array para json só deve ser feita após o `while` pois assim todos os valores são convertidos de um vez só.

Caso queira apenas alguns campos da tabelas e não todos, troque o asterisco pelo nome dos campos.

Mude:

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro
```

Para:

```
SELECT nome, email FROM cadastro
```

Comment: Concordo. Aquele `extract` ali poderia gerar semanas de debug sem entender porque tal variável está com tal valor

Comment: Testei e funcionou, mas apareceu todas as tabelas do BD, como faço para mostrar somente o que eu quero? Deixa a que você criou acima pois ela é muito útil para outras pessoas.

Comment: Eu entendi, mas pedi para dar um segundo exemplo mostrando somente os campos que preciso, mas sem usar o ``extract``, mas sim fazendo da forma correta como mostrou no primeiro código.

Comment: @rray Joia muito obrigado.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk, pensei em tudo, menos no ``SELECT``, kkkkkkkk

Answer (score 3):

Você só pode exibir os dados com `json_encode` fora do `while`, meu amigo.

```
while ($campos = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { 

    extract($campos); 

    $Array[] = Array(
        "nome"  => "$nome",
        "email" => "$email",
    ); 


    //  Melhor assim

    $Array[] = $campos;


} 

echo json_encode($Array);
```

Comment: Fiz isso e retornou nenhum valor.

Comment: Resposta atualizada

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser que esteja indo para o browser alguma saída após o echo. Experimente encerrar o PHP assim `echo json_encode( $resultado); exit();`. No javascript, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
$.post ( url, data, function( response ) {

    // Abra o console do navegador para visualizar esta saída
    console.log( response );

    // Digite seu código aqui

}, 'json' );

// Observe que você pode passar o parâmetro 'json' no final
// para converter a resposta ao invés de usar uma função específica
```